# How to generate the bootstrap 3.0 docs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Might be a stupid question but they moved to Jackyll and i have no idea how to access the docs.

The makefile seems not to do anything then copy some file into docs. Just opening the html files like back in the days not works anymore, some templating has to take place.

Sidequestion: are they available online somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to install ruby that was easy on ubuntu `sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-dev` i believe

the actual command i had to run is `jekyll --server` inside the bs directory then access the docs on localhost `http://localhost:9001`

I don't get this jekyll thing why even a server? Isn't it supposed just compile? Guess not because this is the only way I got it to work and the author showed the exact command on github.

Comment: I had to install jekyll with "gem install jekyll" and run "jekyll serve" instead of "jekyll --server"

Answer (score 3):

As to your side question:  I found this link: http://www.bootcss.com/p/bootstrap-v3/index.html

Beware and expect many changes before 3.0 is final.

Comment: AFAIK jekyll is **not** called during make, i still not know how to compile but now i know how to access the docs with with a localhost server see my andser

Answer (score 1):

In Windows ( perfectly tested by me not sure of linux ) :

> Step1 : Download Bootstrap3 : github.com/twitter/bootstrap/archive/3.0.0-wip.zip 
>   Step2 : Downlaod Ruby : [Click Here](http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/76955/rubyinstaller-2.0.0-p195.exe) 
>   Step3 : Downlaod Devkit : [Click Here](https://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe) and extract it to some directory.
>   Step4 : Go to devkit direcory via ruby terminal and execute following commands

```
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb install
gem install jekyll --version '= 0.11.0'
```

> Step5 : go to the ./docs dir of your bootstrap install
>   Step6 : run jekyll --server 
>   Step7 : visit localhost:9001/ or localhost:4000/ in your browser ( one of them will surely work )